# python Attribute error during object initialization

Tags: python, initialization, attributeerror

Python 2.6.7; Windows 7

Solving Deitel 'Simple Compiler' exercise in python. Repository at [github](https://github.com/Nzen/Simpletron). Writing a test suite.

```
module compiler.py
class SCompiler( object ) :
    RAMSIZE = 100
    # more static attributes

    def __init__( self ) :
        self.symbolTable = [ TableEntry( ) ] * SCompiler.RAMSIZE
        self.lineFlags[ -1 ] * SCompiler.RAMSIZE
        # more initializations
```

Stack trace.

```
File "testCompiler.py", line 45, in <module>
tool = compiler.SCompiler( )
File "absolutePath\compiler.py", line 37, in `__init__`
self.lineFlags[ -1 ] * SCompiler.RAMSIZE
AttributeError: 'SCompiler' object has no attribute 'lineFlags'
```

I'm not sure what there is to misspell here. File 'compiler.py' file compiles silently. TableEntry is another class in the file. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

You get `AttributeError`, because it calls:

```
self.lineFlags[-1]
```

before knowing what `lineFlag` is.

But judging by the line below *(from the file [compiler.py](https://github.com/Nzen/Simpletron/blob/master/compiler.py) in the repository that you linked)*:

```
self.smlData = [ 0 ] * SCompiler.RAMSIZE
```

I think that the author forgot an `=`, try to replace :

```
self.lineFlags[ -1 ] * SCompiler.RAMSIZE
```

with:

```
self.lineFlags = [ -1 ] * SCompiler.RAMSIZE
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize self.lineFlags before trying to treat it like an array.

```
self.lineFlags = []
self.lineFlags[-1] * SCompiler.RAMSIZE
```